# Скорость перевода в нижний регистр

Tags: php

Есть массив, где ключи имеют eng или rus значение. Например,

```
['kEy'=>1, 'клюЧ'=>2]
```

Есть какой-нибудь метод, чтобы привести все ключи к одному регистру (важно, чтобы скорость при этом не хавалась, либо хавалась по минимуму)

Например, array_change_key_case идеально работает по времени для большого массива, но не поддерживает русский. В документации есть "пример" с `mb_convert_case + array_change_key_case` , но с этой комбинацией скорость работы скрипта замедляется в разы. Точно также, как и mb_strtolower.

Если с array_change_key_case скорость работы скрипта 1.5с, то с комбинациями из документации - 12с.

Есть еще способы ? Или это норма и такая вот "особенность" при работе с кириллицей ?

Comment: это какого размера в вас массив? сколько ключей примерно? такие показатели по моему странные.

Comment: ну, массив видимо огромный, а время набегает на цикле, если он делается в php. Врядли есть вариант без него

Comment: Если значение массива не строка то можно через json_encode -> to lower text -> json_decode, при больном массиве этот вариант будет быстрее чем проходиться по массиву

Comment: @ВадимАлександру и тем самым привести к нижнему регистру вообще всё. не катит)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну я написал, если значения не строка или не важен регистр.

Comment: @ВадимАлександру нет, про регистр вы не упомянули

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `Если значение массива не строка то можно через json_encode...` насколько я знаю регистр есть только у строки, можно сделать вывод, что это и имелось ввиду, или я не прав?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру да, не правы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну хорошо, зачем по вашему я написал эту фразу? просто не люблю строковые массивы?

Comment: там размер массива миллионами и десятками миллионов ключей что ли измеряется, что 12сек работает? Какой код вы используете, чтобы изменить ключи в массиве? и да, откуда вы берете массив этот. Пример данных было бы получиьт неплохо

Comment: запустил генерацию 1млн ключей длиной 20 английский алфавит. change_key_case -  700ms.  английский+русский, конвертация через mb_strtolowecase - 800ms

Comment: @teran там идет парсинг xml (большого) и генерация нового xml (также не маленького). Узлы источника сравниваются со справочниками (массивами). Вроде ничего сложного и код наипростейший для обхода по циклу, но почему так происходит по времени - загадка для меня. Стоит убрать конвертацию кириллицы - полет нормальный

Comment: ну так может вы приведете этот самый простейший код?